# Why am I getting this gap in my align?

Tags: equations, align

Everything lines up as I want it to, except the middle part, I don't see why.

```
\begin{align}
\label{eq:energy_conservation_before}
U_b &= -\frac{1}{2} \frac{\mu}{r_b} &&&& V_b &=-\frac{\mu}{r_b} &&&& h_b &= V r_b = \sqrt{\mu r_b}\\
\label{eq:energy_conservation_after}
U_a &= -\frac{1}{2} \frac{\mu}{r_b} (1-\beta) &&&& V_a &=-\frac{\mu}{r} (1-\beta) &&&& h_a &= h_b
\end{align}
```

[image]

Comment: The workings of `align` are described in the `amsmath` user's guide.  I think you might benefit from reading this guide -- `texdoc amsldoc`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question: why didn't you go for this?.

```
\begin{align}
    \label{eq:energy_conservation_before}
    U_b &= -\frac{1}{2} \frac{\mu}{r_b} & V_b &=-\frac{\mu}{r_b} & h_b &= V r_b = \sqrt{\mu r_b}\\
    \label{eq:energy_conservation_after}
    U_a &= -\frac{1}{2} \frac{\mu}{r_b} (1-\beta) & V_a &=-\frac{\mu}{r} (1-\beta) & h_a &= h_b
\end{align}
```

I'm not sure what caused your problem, but you could try putting `&&&` at the end of each line instead of in the middle. See if that's what you want.

Comment: Thought you had to have more &'s to get a gap between equations, but this worked! Thanks!